# What is the technical way to describe growth factors (exponential change in percent)

Tags: math

This may be quite simple, but I'm wondering if there is a technical way to describe a relative value that grows exponentially based on the percentage.

e.g. If these numbers grow by 13.5% every month:

```
100 * 13.5% = 13.5
113.5 * 13.5% = 15.3225
115.3225 * 13.5% = 15.5685375
... etc
```

I am trying to understand the technical or correct way to describe these changes in mathematics. Is there also an equation that would describe this? Thank you to all the math nerds in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se], not programming or software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called a geometric series/sequence.

The generic form is S = a(1 + r^n)

where:
S is the sum of the first n elements of the series.
a is the first element 
r is the multiplication factor 
n is the number of terms.

in your example:
a = 100
r = 0.135
n = is the number you want to compute for. 
if you want the 10th element then n = 10 if you want the 100th element then n = 100.

When you do compound interest calculations you need to be careful as well that the interest you are given is for the year, but the interest is calculated every month so you must adjust your values accordingly.

here is a link to wikipedia that examplains it. At the base it is the same formula but it accounts for all that other stuff I mentioned.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest

Comment: This is very helpful! Thanks! I'm wondering if the same principle is better explained to the general public as just simply as a "Growth Factor?"

Comment: Growth Factor does sound right.. I think though that it would make sense to name r the growth factor, it may actually be called that in biology problems.

Answer (score 0):

[Compounded Annual Growth Rate](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/cagr.asp) would be the investment term where what you want is a slightly different formula as there is a `1.135` factor that is being multiplied with itself to compound the return.

Consider a 10% growth rate and different interest calculations over a few years:

Simple interest for 3 years on $100 would be $10 each for a total of $30.
Compound interest for 3 years on $100 would be $10 for the first year, $11 for the second year and $12.10 for the 3rd year for a total of $33.10 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your calculations are correct?
I think what you're looking for is:

```
 100 * 13,5 % = 13,5 %
(100 + 13,5) * 13,5 % = 15,3225
(100 + 13,5 + 15,3225) * 13,5 % = 17,3910375
```

or in short:

```
100 * 1,135^t
for t=3
100 * 1,135^3 = 146,2135375
```